# What are all needs to be covered in Security Architecture?

Tags: security, architecture

What is the best book for security architecture? is there any security architecture blueprint available?

I am looking from very broad perspective, not just simple authentication, authorization part.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Designing Security Architecture Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471206024) - Jay Ramachandran
- [Building Secure Software: How to Avoid Security Problems the Right Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020172152X) - J.Viega and G.McGraw

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of good resources if you use the search function on SO.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210781/pragmatic-information-security-textbooks) is a result I found under 'Security Book.'  Note that there are even links within that post to other questions asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

Solid theory to apply your own (e.g. commutative ring) from scratch is N.Biggs Discrete mathematics, more applied are have read openbsd.org and insecure.org

Answer (score 0):

[Security Engineering by Ross Anderson](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/book.html) is an excellent text, and the first edition is available for free online.